# Asymptotic decay of $\exp(-\log(x)^a)$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

While trying to figure out whether an integral of the form $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ converges, I bounded $f(x)$ by $\exp(-\log(x)^a)$. This meant that my integral converges if $a>1$ and diverges otherwise.

However, this got me thinking, what is actually the asymptotic decay of $\exp(-\log(x)^a)$?

Initially I assume that it is $O(x^{-a})$, but trying this out numerically, I saw it was not the case. Is this something known?

Comment: Suppose $a>1,\,\epsilon>0$. Since $\ln x^\epsilon<\ln^ax<x^\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $x>0$, $\exp(-\ln^ax)$ decays faster than $1/x^\epsilon$ but not as fast as $\exp(-x^{\epsilon})$.

Comment: @J.G. this is not particularly useful.  For example when $a=1$, this upper bound becomes 1, but $\exp(-\log(x))=1/x$.

Comment: But whenever $a>1$, any power of $x$ is an upper bound.

Comment: @J.G. this cannot be true. If we choose $\epsilon \ll 1$, then $x^{-2}$ decays faster than $exp(-log(x)^{1+\epsilon})$.

Comment: Are you sure? That would imply $2\ln x$ grows faster than $\ln^{1+\epsilon}x$, contradicting $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac12\ln^\epsilon x=\infty$. I think you've confused $\exp(-\ln^ax)$ with $\exp(-a\ln x)$, which is how you thought of $O(x^{-a})$ in the first place.

Comment: @J.G. I think you are right! I have to look at this more carefully...